# Transit at Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport (COVID19)

Tags: transit, covid-19, thailand, bangkok, bkk

Are there any restrictions for transit on Bangkok Suvarnabhumi?
In my case, I am an Austrian citizen traveling from Vienna to Jakarta and will have transit on BKK.

Is there a website providing information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following website gives some information: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> Thailand:

> 1. Passengers and airline crew are not allowed to enter and **transit** until 30 November 2020.
>
> - This does not apply to:
> - nationals and residents of Thailand;
> - passengers who are spouses, parents or children of a national of Thailand;
> - airline crew with a return scheduled flight;
> - passengers with a visa issued by Thailand;
> - nationals of Australia, China (People's Rep.), Japan, Korea (Rep.), Malaysia, New Zealand, Singapore and Viet Nam with an APEC Business
>   Travel Card arriving from the country that issued the APEC Business
>   Travel Card;
> - passengers with a Chinese Taipei (on the cover: Republic of China Taiwan) passport with an APEC Business Travel Card arriving from the
>   country that issued the APEC Business Travel Card;
> - residents of Hong Kong (SAR China) with an APEC Business Travel Card arriving from Hong Kong (SAR China);
> - students.

Indonesia has their own travel restrictions, which you can view on the same website mentioned above. Currently most people can't enter Indonesia.